# Arduino Leonardo, Wire.h throwing errors but no errors when set to Esp32

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to use the library https://github.com/tinovi/i2cArduino
I need to run this on the Arduino Leonardo, but while trying to run it, I get the errors:

```
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'int16_t SVCS3::getVal(byte)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:49:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'uint32_t SVCS3::getVal32(byte)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:65:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'int SVCS3::setReg8(byte, byte)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:83:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'int SVCS3::setReg(byte)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:91:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'int SVCS3::calibrationEC(int16_t)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:114:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr);
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'int SVCS3::newReading()':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:134:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'void SVCS3::getData(float*)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:176:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp: In member function 'void SVCS3::getRaw(byte*)':
/home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:209:32: error: call of overloaded 'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous
   _wire->beginTransmission(addr); // transmit to device
                                ^
In file included from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.h:10:0,
                 from /home/kevin/Arduino/libraries/i2cArduino-master/i2cArduino.cpp:5:
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:61:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t)
     void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kevin/Downloads/arduino ide/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h:62:10: note: candidate: void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)
     void beginTransmission(int);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Leonardo.
```

Strange enough this compiles just fine for the ESP32 platform. Any ideas why Wire.h is failing for the Leonardo???

Answer (score 0):

'beginTransmission(uint16_t&)' is ambiguous

Probably both of your libraries(i2cArduino and Wire) have the same function.
First try to use a exemple only using the wire library then only the i2cArduino library.

So you can make sure the problem is the same function name.
The reason why with the ESP you can compile is probably ESP doesn't use one of the function of the libraries.

To solve you can find another library for the i2c.